# Getting logs filtered in Jenkins build using webhook trigger plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, cicd, flux

I am trying to get a filter message out of the whole received event from the Jenkins job using the webhook trigger plugin and somehow managed to get a message for `Helm upgrade successful` but want to get these Jenkins job triggers for `fail` case as well with below scenario:

- Just want to trigger pipeline only for `helm successful upgrade` or `failed upgrade`. It's working fine for the successful filters but somehow not working when using regexp for both successful and failed scenarios. regexp I am trying currently is `(successfull$)|(failed$)`

[image: Logs which I am receiving in trigger]

[image: Plugin settings which I am trying to use for name value as well]

Comment: Can you please share your Jenkinsfile? It will be easy if you explain the whole scenario of webhook and results.

Comment: @RaviKyada, I am using a simple  Jenkinsfile, I am trying to create a scenario using GitOps Flux.
But thank you for your response I already got a solution for point 1 and looking for help over point 2 ie, trigger only on the basis of successful and failed upgradation of Helm using regExp.. if you have any idea over that would be helpful

Comment: pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage('Hello') {
            steps {
                echo 'Triggered helm name: '+ env.name
                echo 'message: '+ env.message
                echo 'namespace: '+ env.namespace 
            }
        }
    }
}